Defining $T:L^\infty(\mu)\rightarrow L^\infty(\nu)$ with integrals
I was reading a measure theory book (Fremlin, vol 4) where it states that given two probability spaces $(X,\Sigma_X,\mu),(Y,\Sigma_Y,\nu)$ and $f:X\rightarrow Y$ a measurable function such that $\nu$ is the pushforward measure of $\mu$ with respect to $f$, i.e. $\nu(F)=\mu(f^{-1}(F))$ for every $F\in\Sigma_Y$, then we can define a linear operator $T:L^\infty(\mu)\rightarrow L^\infty(\nu)$ by saying that $\int_FT(u)=\int_{f^{-1}(F)}u$ for every $u\in L^\infty(\mu),\ F\in\Sigma_Y$, where the integral of an equivalence class is defined as the integral of a generic member of the equivalence class (i.e. $\int_A[f]=\int_Afd\mu$ if $[f]\in L^\infty(\mu)$).
How can we do that? Why we can say that this defines an element $T(u)\in L^\infty(\nu)$? Probably the change of variables formula for pushforward measures is involved, but I cannot say how.

A more precise reference than volume 4 might be helpful. Fremlin tends to be quite detailed.

@MichaelGreinecker Theorem 452I.

Your formula defines a signed measure $\lambda$ on $Y$ via
$$
\lambda(F):=\int_{f^{-1}(F)} u \,\mathrm{d}\mu \qquad\forall F\in \Sigma_Y.$$
One can check that
$$
|\lambda(F)|\le C\nu(F) \qquad\forall F \in \Sigma_Y.
$$
Consequently, the Radon-Nikodým derivative of $\lambda$ w.r.t. $\nu$ belongs to $L^\infty(\nu)$. This derivative is called $T(u)$ by Fremlin.
